# Cannot Perform Any Code in IBAction after getting network request

Tags: ios, swift, networking, ibaction

I am trying to transition into a new segue after I confirm that I get a the session ID from the Udacity API. However, I cannot get any code to run after this. The session ID and all the information will print, but nothing will complete after. Is there something I am doing wrong in the function? I tried performing the UIUpdates then just tried printing "Hello" but that has not worked either. Below is some code and also my GitHub profile.
https://github.com/SteveBurgos95/UdacityMapProject

```
    @IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: Any) {
UdacityClient.sharedInstance().loginWithUsername(emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!){ (success, error) in
    performUIUpdatesOnMain {
        if success {
            print("Hello")
        } else {
            print("Hey")
        }
    }
}

private func completeLogin() {
emailTextField.text = ""
let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TableMapViewController") as! UINavigationController
present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Do you see anything when printing before the performUIUpdatesOnMain closure?

Comment: @peter Yes I will get something similiar to this printed out. Which is the expected behavior for the API . 



  {  
    "account":{  
        "registered":true,
        "key":"3903878747"
    },
    "session":{  
        "id":"1457628510Sc18f2ad4cd3fb317fb8e028488694088",
        "expiration":"2015-05-10T16:48:30.760460Z"
    }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me like you're never calling your completionhandler in `UdacityClient.swift` when the dataTask finishes (both in case of error and success)?

This should be something like this:

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in

    // Make sure there is no error, or else
    guard error == nil else { // Handle error…

      completionHandler(false, error?.localizedDescription)
      /*
         func sendError(_ error: String) {
         print(error)
         let userInfo = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : error]
         completionHandlerForGET(nil, NSError(domain: "taskForGETMethod", code: 1, userInfo: userInfo))
        */
        return
    }

    completionHandler(true, nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking through the code the UI is not getting updated because your have not implemented the `sucess` block in `UdacityClient.swift`. The `sucess` block/closure `escapes`. So you won't receive a callback in

`UdacityClient.sharedInstance().loginWithUsername(emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!){`

Answer (score -1):

Change the function like below

```
     func loginWithUsername(_ username: String, password: String, completionHandler: @escaping (_ success: Bool, _ errorMessage: String?) -> Void ) {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.udacity.com/api/session")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        request.httpBody = "{\"udacity\": {\"username\": \"\(username)\", \"password\": \"\(password)\"}}".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
            if error != nil 
                // Handle error…
              /*
                 func sendError(_ error: String) {
                 print(error)
                 let userInfo = [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : error]
                 completionHandlerForGET(nil, NSError(domain: "taskForGETMethod", code: 1, userInfo: userInfo))
                */

                return
            }
           completionHandler(true,nil)
            let range = Range(5..<data!.count)
            let newData = data?.subdata(in: range) /* subset response data! */
            print(NSString(data: newData!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!)
        }
        task.resume()
        }
```

Comment: The if statement in this solution is inverted from the original piece of code, the condition is now `error == nil` instead of `error != nil` which makes the rest of the closure non-sense.

Also, this will only work in case the login in a success and will have the same bug when the login fails.

Please check my solution for a more complete solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45026732/1415898